# fadeIn of parent div that contains child elements with various display tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm using a function to load content (html code), and after that is loaded, I use the fadeIn function to slowly fade in the div container the content was loaded inside. The html code loaded is dynamic and can be pretty much anything.

So it can happen that loaded html code has already display tags assigned via css (e.g. table, table-cell), and that seems to screws with the fadeIn animation of the parent div, making those child divs just pop up instead of fade in.

So how can I get a fadeIn function of a parent div to include every kind of child divs that may have all sort of display tags? Is there a way at all?

Thanks in advance,
ANB_Seth

Comment: jQuery has children selector: https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue you describe in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .children() method in jQuery to target all children in a parent element. See the docs for this method [here](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

Bind an event to trigger the fadeIn. In this example I have just used a click event but you could use anything else, perhaps on load.

```
$(".myParent").on("click", function () {
    $(this).children().fadeIn(); 
});
```